How to track my code coverage report in azure devops on dashboard or something similar?
I have a pipeline which generates code coverage report as an artifact, It contains a set of 32 html files and a summary. Now I want to track these on azure devops or something similar how can I do it

Please share the pipeline definition(yaml) about how you generate the coverage report with html file. Did you generate it from coverage.xml via task reportgenerator@5?

Yes I have generated it from coverage.xml

the html files are human readable, it's not needed for coverage tracking on devops. Please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries, glad to help.

You are welcome. Feel free to let me know if you still have any queries.


How to track my code coverage report in azure devops on dashboard or something similar?

code coverage detail is tracked on pipeline run result page not dashboard. You can check the official doc Review code coverage results for the details.
There is only 3rd-party extension(here and here) to track coverage result on dashboard, but it only shows little info which is not recommended.
hmtl files are human readable, it's not needed now for coverage tracking.
To track the code coverage on pipeline result, it could be different due to the task used:

You can use task Publish Code Coverage Results which requires the coverage.xml. sample link.

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  displayName: Publish code coverage results
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: "coverage.xml" 


Built-in tasks such as Visual Studio Test, .NET Core, Ant, Maven, Gulp, Grunt, and Gradle provide the option to publish code coverage data to the pipeline.

For example:

Please check the link below for the details.

